# Laravel Pivot Table With Result From Other Table

Tags: laravel

I'm confused about the relationship pivot table with the result.
for example :
I have 3 tables + 1 table for insert data

```
structurals
    id
    name

indicators
    id
    name

structural_indicator (Pivot Table)
    id
    structural_id
    indicator_id

quality_indicators (Insert Table)
    id
    structural_indicator_id
    numerator_score
    denominator_score
    date_at
```

**And This my relationships:**

```
    //Indicator Model
    public function structurals() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Structural::class, 'structural_indicator');
    }

    //Structural Model
    public function Indicators() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Indicator::class, 'structural_indicator')
                ->withPivot(['id']);
    }
```

For relationship with pivot table, it's no problem.

But I want a relationship pivot table with insert table (quality_indicators), search by `structural_id` and by `date_at`, and show result pivot table with quality_indicators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create `StructuralIndicatorPivotModel` as follows

```
<?php

namespace yournamespace;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StructuralIndicatorPivotModel extends Model
{
    /**
     *
     */
    protected $table = 'structural_indicator';

    /**
     *
     */
    protected $with = ['qualityIndicator'];

    /**
     *
     */
    public function qualityIndicator()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(QualityIndicator::class, 'structural_indicator_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Then you need to add relation with pivot table in both `Indicator` and `Structural` Model
***Indicator*** Model

```
<?php

namespace yournamespace;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Indicator extends Model
{
    /**
     *
     */
    public function structurals() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Structural::class, 'structural_indicator');
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function structuralIndicatorPivot() {
        return $this->hasMany(StructuralIndicatorPivotModel::class, 'indicator_id');
    }
}
```

***Structural*** Model

```
<?php

namespace yournamespace;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Structural extends Model
{
    /**
     *
     */
   public function indicators() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Indicator::class, 'structural_indicator');
}

    /**
     *
     */
    public function structuralIndicatorPivot() {
        return $this->hasMany(StructuralIndicatorPivotModel::class, 'structural_id');
    }
}
```

So now you can write your query as `Structural::where('id', 'someId')->with('structuralIndicatorPivot')->get()` OR `Indicator::where('id', 'someId')->with('structuralIndicatorPivot')->get()` and `quality_indicators` data will automatically be loaded as it is associated with `$with` of `StructuralIndicatorPivotModel`.

Comment: it's work if i'm using StructuralIndicatorPivotModel::find($id);. But I want use Structural::find($id) ?. I'm used Structural::find($id)->indicator, i'm success show data from pivot table, but i want every indicator with qualityIndicator result.

Comment: The above model is not to call `find()` on it. But to use the `$with` that will serve the purpose of automatically loading `qualityIndicator` every time the pivot is called.

Comment: thanks sir, That's really remarkable. but i have one problem, when I have condition by date_at from quality_indicators table. `->whereHas('structuralIndicatorPivot.qualityIndicator', function($query) {
                $query->where('date_at', '2021-05-19');
            })`. if not same with the date, result null. I want result always show and structuralIndicatorPivot.qualityIndicator result is null

Comment: sir, thanks for your all answers.
question has been closed. this is my syntax
`$structural = Structural::where('id', $id)
            ->with(['indicators', 'structuralIndicatorPivot' => function($query) {
                $query->with('qualityIndicator', function($q){
                    $q->where('date_at', '2021-05-19');
                });
            }])
            ->first();`

Answer (score 0):

I'm try using this dependency
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

But Error:

> Call to undefined relationship [pivot] on model [App\Models\Indicator].

This is my models and pivot

```
class Structural extends Model
{

    public function indicators()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Indicator::class, 'structural_indicator')
                    ->withPivot(['id'])
                    ->using(StructuralIndicator::class);
    }

    public function qualityIndicator(){
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Indicator::class,
            [StructuralIndicator::class, QualityIndicator::class],
            ['structural_id', 'structural_indicator_id'],
            ['id', 'id']
        );
    }
}

class Indicator extends Model
{
    public function structurals()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Structural::class, 'structural_indicator')->using(StructuralIndicator::class);
    }
}

class StructuralIndicator extends Pivot
{
    public function structural(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Structural::class);
    }
    
    public function indicator(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Indicator::class);
    }

    public function qualityIndicator()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(QualityIndicator::class, 'structural_indicator_id');
    }
}

class QualityIndicator extends Model
{
    public function structuralIndicator()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(StructuralIndicator::class, 'structural_indicator_id');
    }
}
```

And this my code in controller:

```
$structural = Structural::with('indicators')->with('indicators.pivot.qualityIndicator')->where('id', 6)->first();
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. It is now working perfectly fine. Just give it a try.